# How to instruct ProGuard to completely remove a particular class from the build?

Tags: java, android, proguard

On an Android App (Hybrid Capacitor/Android App) I have a flag on my BuildConfig called `LIVE_RELOAD`. When it is set to true, I load a plugin that disables SSL Checking so I can use a self-signed certificate while doing development.

The `MainActivity` looks like this:

```java
public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {

    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.registerLiveReload();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

  private void registerLiveReload(){
    if (BuildConfig.LIVE_RELOAD) {
      Log.w(TAG, "⚠️  Registering SSL IGNORE FOR LIVERELOAD  ⚠️");
      registerPlugin(SSLCheckSkipForDevelopmentPlugin.class); // <- HERE
    }
  }
}
```

I want to instruct ProGuard to completely remove `registerLiveReload` and `SSLCheckSkipForDevelopmentPlugin` from the APK but I am unable to do it.

In `build.gradle` I have set this on `buildTypes -> release`

```
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            manifestPlaceholders.cleartextTrafficPermitted ="false"
        }
```

and my proguard-rules.pro looks like:

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile

-assumenosideeffects class com.domain.myapp.MainActivity{
  private void registerLiveReload();
}

-dontwarn com.domain.myapp.SSLCheckSkipForDevelopmentPlugin
-assumenosideeffects class com.domain.myapp.SSLCheckSkipForDevelopmentPlugin {
    *;
}
```

But when I build the APK and analyze it, I still can see the class being referenced there:

[image]

What I am missing?